# How to persist a BottomNavigationBar across to screens using onGenerateRoute?

Tags: flutter, flutter-navigation

I'm trying to implement a simple BottomNavigationBar to navigate across the screens that I dynamically generate.

Having a React.js background I thought of having some kind of wrapper around my screens that would contain the BottomNavigationBar and render screens as children according to the current route. But there's no way to append a child when defining a MaterialApp widget so that BottomNavigationBar is present and somehow wraps around the screens from onGenerateRoute. The only other way I see is to pass my BottomNavigationBar to every screen as a bottomNavigationBar property within a Scaffold. But it doesn't seem to be an optimal thing to do.

Here's my Router:

```
class Router {
  static Route<dynamic> generateRoute(RouteSettings settings) {
    final args = settings.arguments;

    switch (settings.name) {
      case '/':
        return MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (BuildContext context) => Home(),
        );
      default:
        return MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (BuildContext context) => Error(),
        );
    }
  }
}
```

The router I pass to the onGenerateRoute property of the MaterialApp widget:

```
class App extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      initialRoute: '/',
      onGenerateRoute: Router.generateRoute,
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: You should probably have a single page with the BottomNavigationBar in the Home. The pages reachable from that bar should be displayed by using a PageView. Don't create a route for each page, place all the pages reachable by the navigation bar into a PageView and display them accordingly to what was tapped on the bar.

Comment: @Bob, I've seen a few PageView implementations while searching for the way to use the BottomNavigationBar but thought there would be a way to stick to the onGenereateRoute one. So, currently, I need to use different routing technics according to the way my UI  is, right?

Comment: If you want to keep different routes, the only solution I can think of is to make a separate widget for the bottom navigation bar (just to avoid copy & pasting it's implementation on every screen), somehow keep track on what's currently pressed in the navigation bar and use that widget on every screen. I know that there are some ways for listening to changes in the current route, but have no idea on how to link that to the bottom navigation bar

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look into [CupertinoTabScaffold](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/cupertino/CupertinoTabScaffold-class.html) with [CupertinoTabBar](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/cupertino/CupertinoTabBar-class.html). Apparently they adhere to Apple's design philosophy, where each tab has its own Navigator. Then the tab bar should stay put even if you navigate to a new page from the 'main' page of one of the tabs to new/sub routes. They can be used in a MaterialApp too so that shouldn't be an issue.

I myself am struggling with this issue since I'm passing some pretty complex data to some of the generated routes and I'm using a custom BottomAppBar for design purposes, and it always leads to either my initialRoute when I click on the tab. If that's something you're trying to overcome then sorry I don't have the answer for that one yet...lmk if that's what you're trying to accomplish and I'll remove my answer/update if I've found that answer by then!